# Is there any way to know the RTT in datalink layer?

Tags: java, android, data-link-layer

I'm trying to find a way to know RTT during my android phone and the router. I'm not sure whether there is a way to find that.
Dose anyone know some of this field knowledge?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think, that there is a way to read the value from the link layer, but there is a WiFi standard 802.11mc, which includes some kind of rtt measurement.

Unfortunately, Android has only a hidden system api up to now and an app using this api has to be installed in priv-app folder which requires root.

More information can be found in this Github-project: [Android RTTManagerCompat](https://github.com/Plinzen/android-rttmanager-compat)